# React Native: Run actions after succesfully logged in

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm creating a React Native app in which some actions like adding to favorites require the user to be logged in.

### The problem

If a certain action needs authentication, the following flow is executed:

1. User tab over the favorite button(Protected action)
2. A modal(screen with presentation: "modal") is rendered to allow the user to enter their credentials
3. If the user is successfully logged in, the modal is closed and the user is directed to the screen on which it was located(`goBack()` navigation action).
4. **THE PROBLEM**: user needs to press again over the favorite button, the idea is, if the user is successfully logged in, the action (add to favorites) is executed immediately without the user having to perform the action again.

**NOTE**: I can have different protected actions on the same screen

### Question

how can I request the user to log in to perform the action and have the action executed automatically after successful login?
**execute the protected action only once, only when the user logs in successfully and the modal is closed, if the user is already authenticated the protected action should not be executed again.**

### Example flow

```js
function FavoriteScreen({ navigation }) {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth();

  if (isAuthenticated) {
      addFavorite(productId);
  } else {
    navigation.navigate("LoginScreen");
  }
}
```

### Things I've tried

1. Send a callback through the parameters(called `nexAction`) from the protected action screen to the login screen, run the callback after successfully log in, and close the modal, but I'm getting [non-serializable](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/troubleshooting/#i-get-the-warning-non-serializable-values-were-found-in-the-navigation-state) warning, and this screen implements deep linking, so I cannot ignore the warning as the documentation suggests.

```js
if (isAuthenticated) {
  addFavorite();
} else {
  navigation.navigate(NavigationScreens.LoginScreen, {
    nextAction: addFavorite,
  });
}
```

2. Use the `focus` event to run the protected action after the user is successfully logged in and the modal is closed. This approach has some problems, each time user focuses on the screen and is authenticated, the protected action is going to be run, and there may be more than one protected action on the screen, meaning that they will all be executed when the screen is focused.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      addFavorite();
    }
  });

  return unsubscribe;
}, [isAuthenticated, navigation, addFavorite]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried an effect?

```
// Will run once on mount and again when auth state changes
useEffect(() => {
  if (isAuth) {
    // code runs when auth changes from false to true
  } else {
    // code runs when auth changes to false
  }
}, [isAuth]);
```

You can't send a function on nav params, but you can send data. You can try parroting the data back from the login screen and performing your one time action like this:

```
const Fav = ({ route }) => {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth();

  const {nextAction} = route.params;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      // If login navigated back to us with a nextAction, complete it now
      if (nextAction === CallbackActions.ADD_FAVORITE) addFavorite();
    } else {
      navigation.navigate(NavigationScreens.LoginScreen, {
        nextAction: CallbackActions.ADD_FAVORITE, // Send some data to the login screen
      });
    }
  }, []);
};

const Login = ({ route }) => {
  const {nextAction} = route.params;

  // Do login stuff
  login().then(() => {
      navigation.navigate(NavigationScreens.FavoriteScreen, {
        nextAction, // Send back the caller's nextAction
      });
  });
};
```

Comment: the solution you propose could present a problem, suppose I create the effect on the favorites screen, this favorites screen could have other actions that need login, with the effect whenever the user logs in the effect would be executed no matter the type of action.

Comment: You will have to update your question with an example that illustrates this problem.

Comment: Updated my question by adding more context and some options I have tried

Comment: Do you use the navigator to go to the modal? If so then you'll have to pass it some data to use in its .navigate call. `{ onSuccessLoginNav: {name: "fave", params: {loginSuccess: true}} }`. Then when FavoriteScreen mounts again you can check for that nav param and run your logic. This way the params are just data so it can be serialized, you just need to inject the navigator into your modal component as well.

Comment: what you mean is that I should implement these flags on each of the screens where I need to execute protected actions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right path with `useEffect`. What about storing the user action when clicking a protected action, and then performing the action and clearing the stored value after the user has logged in?

Something like:

`const [pendingAction, setPendingAction] = useState();`

user clicks addFavorite action, but is not logged in:

`setPendingAction({type: 'addFavorite', value: 12});`

Then handling the login in the modal, the previous screen will stay mounted and keep its state.

And then calling the pendingAction in the `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (isAuth) {
    if (pendingAction) {
      switch(pendingAction.type) {
        // do something
      }
      setPendingAction(undefined);
    }
  } else {
    // code runs when auth changes to false
  }
}, [isAuth, pendingAction, setPendingAction]);
```